# Update / Install the newest version of LaTeX3

Tags: installing, latex3, updating

The developing of LaTeX3 goes on. However some feature will be improved or added. The LaTeX3 team can't upload every day a new version to CTAN.

How can I install the newest version LaTeX3?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The LaTeX3 team is well presented in the web. The current development branch is available at [LaTeX Project - Source repository](http://www.latex-project.org/svnroot/experimental/trunk/)

To download the newest version you can use svn.

#### For Unix users

The following command download the complete trunk folder to the current folder of your opened terminal

```bsh
~$ svn co http://www.latex-project.org/svnroot/experimental/trunk/
```

The LaTeX3 team provide a great combination of `Makefile` so you can use the following command to install the current branch to your local texmf tree.

```bsh
~$ cd trunk
~$ make localinstall
```

A small script can be

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
# small script to use the newest svn-version of LaTeX3
echo "Install LaTeX3"
cd $HOME
mkdir tmpinstallfolder-latex3
cd tmpinstallfolder-latex3
svn co http://www.latex-project.org/svnroot/experimental/trunk/
cd trunk
make localinstall
cd $HOME
rm -rfv tmpinstallfolder-latex3
echo "Install LaTeX3 done"
```

#### For Windows users

To download the svn repository you can use the GUI [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/) or the command line version [SlikkSVN](http://www.sliksvn.com/en/download). The repository is

```
http://www.latex-project.org/svnroot/experimental/trunk/
```

The LaTeX3 team provides a file `make.bat` which works like the Unix file `Makefile`. You can use

```
make localinstall
```