# Installation of siunitx and LaTeX 3

Tags: siunitx, latex3

I am interested in using the package `siunitx`.  However, it appears that I need to be running LaTeX 3 in order to do this.  The installation information on CTAN seems somewhat cryptic, and I am confused about how to do the upgrade.  Right now I am using MikTeX and what I think is LaTeX2e.  Can anyone help a relative newbie?  Alternatively, if you could point me to another post that answers this, that would be great too.  Thanks!

Comment: one day latex3 might be a separate format but currently you just need the tex macros which are designed to run as packages with LaTeX2e. siunitx tends to need the latest versions so if you have just installed that you probably need to update expl3 packages as well, but then just use latex2e as normal.

Comment: Just use the MikTeX package manager (or its auto-installation) feature to install `siunitx`. Then everything should just work. You virtually never need to install a package by hand (especially not a popular one like `siunitx`).

Comment: Assuming your MiKTeX is recent, you should have no issues as noted. The only thing to watch is that MiKTeX 'stumbles' if you installed the older `expl3` and `xpackages` bundles. Make sure these are removed in the package manager if present, otherwise odd things will happen.

Comment: See: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55614/update-install-the-newest-version-of-latex3

Answer (score 8):

At present, 'LaTeX3' is a series of packages which can be used with LaTeX2e (the current standard LaTeX). As such, all that is needed by a user is to load the appropriate packages. `siunitx` will do this itself, so all you should need to use the package is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
```

MiKTeX should automatically any missing packages when you do this. Thus in the first instance you should just try the above.

If you have automatic installation of packages turned off, then you will need to install `l3kernel` and `l3packages` by hand using the MiKTeX Package Manager. Both should be listed and install with no issues.

Very occasionally, it is necessary with MiKTeX to get the package manager 'back on track' due to some file renaming which the LaTeX3 team did a while ago. If the MiKTeX Package Manager lists '`expl3`' or '`xpackages`' as installed, you will need to tell it to remove them and install `l3kernel` and `l3packages` instead.