# TeX Live, Ubuntu - Update expl3 to l3kernel problem

Tags: texlive, ubuntu, expl3

I'm a noob with LaTeX.

Trying to get my [`import`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/import/) package to work, I came across a dependency on the `ExplFileVersion` macro. Googling this issue, I realized I need to update my [`l3kernel`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel) package.

The trouble is, `l3kernel` package doesn't exist on my system where the other TeX packages do (seemingly `/usr/share/texmf-texlive`).
I did however find the following package: `/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/expl3`.
To my understanding this is the older version, which has to be replaced with `l3kernel`.

I'm an Ubuntu 10.4 user, and I installed using `apt-get` the following packages: `texlive`, `texlive-full`, `texlive-latex-recommended` (which supposedly contains `l3kernel`) and `texlive-latex3`.

I tried to download `l3kernel` and manually compile it with LaTeX, but it won't compile. If however somebody here thinks this is the correct way to go, I'll post the errors.

Does anyone know what's to be done next?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: See: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55614/update-install-the-newest-version-of-latex3

Comment: Ubuntu 10.4 is unsupported. Either upgrade or install vanilla TeXLive.

Answer (score 6):

The Ubuntu packages lag a *long* way behind the current TeX Live releases: the exact lag does vary, but it's always there. You will need to do a 'local' installation of [`l3kernel`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/install/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel.tds.zip) and [`l3packages`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/install/macros/latex/contrib/l3packages.tds.zip). Both are available in 'ready-to-install' TDS-style zip files, so you just need to download them and unzip in the appropriate place.

There are two options to this: if you are the only user of your Ubuntu system, the easiest is to place them in your personal tree, `~/texmf`. That doesn't need anything other than running the unzip. The alternative is to install them in the 'system-wide' local tree, `/usr/local/share/texmf`. For that, you'll need write privileges (`sudo` or similar), and will also need to run `sudo texhash` after unzipping to update your file database.