# How to update glossaries package on Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: installing, texlive, glossaries, ubuntu

My `texlive` version is

```
$ tex -version
TeX 3.1415926 (TeX Live 2012/Debian)
kpathsea version 6.1.0
Copyright 2012 D.E. Knuth.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the TeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the TeX source.
Primary author of TeX: D.E. Knuth.
```

I need to upgrade the `glossaries` package to the latest version `v3.07 (2013/07/05)`

My OS is Ubuntu 12.10

How to upgrade to the latest version of glossaries package?

Thanks.

Comment: To update only that package, download the TDS `.zip` [`glossaries`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/install/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries.tds.zip) and then follow the instructions in [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/124800/27635).

Comment: :).. done. I had to download `glossaries.tds.zip`, `xfor.tds.zip`, `etoolbox.tds.zip` and `datatool.tds.zip` from he link `http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/install/macros/latex/contrib` first in `~/Download/` folder. Then unzipped all the .zip files in folder `/usr/local/share/texmf` using the command, for example,  `$sudo unzip ~/Download/glossaries.tds.zip -d /usr/local/share/texmf` and finally `$ sudo texhash`. It works now. Thanks a lot. Took hint from the link http://www.maxmanders.co.uk/2012/01/05/missing-ubuntulatex-glossaries.html

Comment: @cosmicraga You may write a short answer to your own question and check it. The question will then be closed as "answerd".

Answer (score 4):

I had to download `glossaries.tds.zip`, `xfor.tds.zip`, `etoolbox.tds.zip` and `datatool.tds.zip` from the link http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/install/macros/latex/contrib first in

> ~/Downloads/

folder. Then unzipped all the .zip files in folder

> /usr/local/share/texmf

using the command, for example,

```
$sudo unzip ~/Downloads/glossaries.tds.zip -d /usr/local/share/texmf
```

and finally

```
$ sudo texhash
```

It works now. Thanks a lot. 
Took hint from the link http://www.maxmanders.co.uk/2012/01/05/missing-ubuntulatex-glossaries.html

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer! FYI, I had to download 'tracklang.tds.zip' and unpack it to '/usr/local/share/texmf', in addition to the other '*.tds.zip' packages. This is most likely due to updates in the glossaries package over the last two years :)